Issue with sum advanced sum.
my friend has sent me this series problem
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1\cdot4\cdot7\cdots(3n-2))}{5^n \cdot n!}$
And he showed me that it converges to
$(\frac{5}{2})^{1/3} -1$
Wich is
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^n \cdot n!} \displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n 3k-2$
But when I write
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{3k-2}{5^n \cdot n!}$ I got a different result, but they must be the same
Since the term $5^n×n!$ is constant in $k$ so the multiplication must be commutative and the index Don't effects, but why does this happened?

In your version, aren't you multiplying by $ 1/( 5^n \cdot n!) $ $n$ times? So please clarify how thy are the same?  IE You're saying that $ \alpha \times (a)(b)(c) = (\alpha a ) (\alpha b) (\alpha c)$.

I'm sorry I didn't notice this stupid mistake

If you write $$\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{3k-2}{5^n \cdot n!},$$
that means
$$\frac{1}{5^n \cdot n!} \cdot \frac{4}{5^n \cdot n!} \cdot \frac{7}{5^n \cdot n!} \cdots \frac{3n-2}{5^n \cdot n!}.$$
In other words, each factor in the product has been divided by $5^n \cdot n!$, for the same reason that
$$\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2} = \frac{n!}{2^n}.$$

True, I didn't notice that.

I don't how I didn't notice this stupid mistake

Because it's the product of a_n over the product of b_n,

A product $\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^n \lambda u_k$ is not equal to $\displaystyle \lambda \prod_{k=1}^n u_k$, but to $\lambda^n \displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^n u_k$, since each of the $n$ factors is multiplied by $\lambda$.

Yes sorry I didn't notice

You can move a constant into a sum because of the distributive law: $a\cdot(b+c) = (a\cdot b) + (a\cdot c)$
But you can't do this with a product because generally $a\cdot(b\cdot c) \neq (a\cdot b)\cdot (a\cdot c)$.
Instead, the law $c\cdot\left(\sum a_n\right) = \sum (c\cdot a_n)$ corresponds to the law $\left(\prod a_n\right)^c = \prod(a_n)^c$.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {1 \times 4\times 7\times\cdots\times\pars{3n - 2} \over 5^{n}\ n!}} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\prod_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\,\pars{3k + 1} \over 5^{n}\ n!}
\\[5mm] = & \
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{3^{n}\,\Gamma\pars{1/3 + n}/\Gamma\pars{1/3} \over 5^{n}\ n!} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{n - 2/3}! \over n!\pars{-2/3}!}
\pars{3 \over 5}^{n}
\\[5mm] = & \
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{n - 2/3 \choose n}
\pars{3 \over 5}^{n} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\bracks{{-1/3 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}}
\pars{3 \over 5}^{n}
\\[5mm] = & \
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{-1/3 \choose n}
\pars{-\,{3 \over 5}}^{n} = \bracks{1 + \pars{-\,{3 \over 5}}}^{-1/3} - {-1/3 \choose 0}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\pars{5 \over 2}^{1/3} - 1}} \approx
0.3572 \\ &
\end{align}

Sir, I'm not asking about how to evaluate it, your post doesn't answer my question , I've just made a terrible mistake that I didn't notice, and finally I have noticed it
